# How to bind parameters in a procedural way

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, pdo

My team and I are trying to bind parameters in a procedural way based on what was done with PDO in php but when we did we got the following error :

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given**

The original PDO **working** code that we want to turn into procedural is:

```
    $last_id = $_POST['last_id'];
$limit = 5; // default value
if (isset($_POST['limit'])) {
    $limit = intval($_POST['limit']);
}

try {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE id > :last_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, :limit';
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':last_id', $last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $list = $query->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDOException : '.  $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Here is what we did to turn that into a procedural :

```
$last_id = $_POST['last_id'];
$limit = 5; // default value
if (isset($_POST['limit'])) {
    $limit = intval($_POST['limit']);
}


 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT id, photo, title, description FROM items WHERE id > ?  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, ?") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $last_id, $limit) or die(mysqli_error($connection));



    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2,$col3, $col4) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

########################################





$last_id = 0;


while( $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) 
{
    $last_id = $rs['id'];
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<h2>'.$rs['title'].'</h2>';
    echo '<img src="'.$rs['photo'].'">';
    echo '<p>'.$rs['description'].'</p>';
    echo '</li>';
}



if ($last_id != 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var last_id = '.$last_id.';</script>';
}
```

**PROBLEM**
With our procedural method, we kept on getting the following error message :

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given**

After some [search](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) we can not really tell where we are mistaking in the **mysqli_stmt_bind_result** or **mysqli_fetch_assoc()**

**QUESTION :**
Please How to bind parameters in a procedural way  ?

Comment: Instead of `select *` you have to use `SELET col1,col2` and in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2)` also `$last_id, $limit` is `int` so use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii'`

Comment: Change `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $last_id, $limit)` to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2,$col3, $col4)`

Comment: @Saty I just did and now it throws another error  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

Comment: Use `while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }`

Comment: @Saty Cool. It worked. Now can you please explain the last part and post it as an answer so that I may validate it . Please kindly explain how i can use each var desperately like the variable containing the title separately form other variables and add it as answer. Thanks

Comment: I make it as answer plz chack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this document [mysqli_stmt_bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

You need to change your query to  `SELECT col1,col2.....` instead instead of `select *`

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $last_id, $limit) or die(mysqli_error($connection));// here use int because `$last_id, $limit` are integer
    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2,$col3, $col4) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

To fetch data use

```
 /* fetch values */

 while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain  ``printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);`` ? Supposed that I only want to display the title which is for example coming from the database as a column name "title", what should I do ? Thanks

Comment: `$col1` is the first column value form select query `SELECT col1` and so on.

Comment: Or you can use as `SELECT id, photo, title, description FROM...` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $photo,$title, $description)` and `while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $id, $photo,$title, $description);
    }`